# Resilience4j: Combine Bulkhead with TimeLimiter for a synchronous external system call from Tomcat

Tags: java, resilience4j

I have a web application running in a Tomcat server that performs calls to an external server.
Now, I want to use Resilience4j's `TimeLimiter` to retrict the waiting time for the response and additionally a `Bulkhead` to limit the amount of parallel calls to the external server.

I don't need asynchronous calls to the external system as the Tomcat thread has to wait for the response or timeout, anyway.

What would be the best way to combine the `TimeLimiter` and the `Bulkhead` in this scenario? Do I need a `SemaphoreBulkhead` or the `ThreadPoolBulkhead` and how would I wrap my external system call in a `Future` that is needed for the `TimeLimiter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't combine a SemaphoreBulkhead and a TimeLimiter, since the TimeLimiter cannot stop the execution of a task if it is running the same Thread.

Therefore you can only combine a TimeLimiter and a ThreadPoolBulkhead. But it only makes sense if you want to have a non-blocking/async code and not block your Thread.

If you want blocking code, you could just use:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.method()).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you want non-blocking code and you can use Java9 or greater, you can just do:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.method()).orTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The new `orTimeout` operator is comparable to Resilience4j TimeLimiter.

If you have to use Java8 and want to use Resilience4j, then do

```
ThreadPoolBulkhead bulkhead = ThreadPoolBulkhead.ofDefaults("sample");
TimeLimiter timeLimiter = TimeLimiter.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
CompletableFuture<String> future = timeLimiter
    .executeCompletionStage(scheduler, 
        bulkhead.decorateSupplier(() -> service.method())).toCompletableFuture();
```

The TimeLimiter allows to use your own ScheduledExecutorService, whereas the new `orTimeout` operator does not.

I suggest to read this blog post -> http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html